# Can we make how long questions will be featured depend on the bounty amount?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I have seen that for any question, if we assign 50/100/200 or any amount of bounty, but the time duration for question appeared in featured is 7 days.

So can we have modification like duration vary as per bounty amount?

**Lets look at pros:**

- User will not require to reassign bountry if question not answered within 7 days.
- More bounty gets more visibility time.
- Let's questioner decide for how much time he/she wants to advertise their question.

**Lets look at Cons:**

- Existing system is also provide such facility as per [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325833/631652)

If my point is wrong then direct me with correct answer.

Comment: Why should it vary? You need to provide a justification for this change.

Comment: @RobertLongson I guess he means to say , if you pay more bounty you get featured longer.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's as simple as that, if you pay more then you may get more!

Comment: Is there any reason to advertise anything beyond 2 weeks? If you cannot solve your problem by then, then you will probably get fired anyways. Would you prefer 70 days of visibility for your, pardon me, silly question?

Comment: That's not a reason to make a change, you need to explain what benefit it would have.

Comment: @Matsmath are you serious? Every problem must be answered in 2 weeks? There may be several questions which might require time, but let's decide questioner that how much time he can wait for the answer. We should not decide that answer can be given within a week or two.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't have that much lengthy set of explanation. I have updated question.

Comment: The trouble is most people answering bounties only look at them when there's one day to go (instant gratification must be in vogue or something). This proposal would just extend the unloved time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already possible, sort of ...

If you spend 50 reputation on the bounty and are not satisfied with the results after a week, you can offer an additional bounty which lasts another week. This way, you can get a longer attention span for your question, but this will be more costly.

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

At the cost of 750 reputation (50+100+200+400), your question will be featured for a full four weeks.

Comment: I agree that 750 bounty would last long for 4 weeks. But after each week, user has to reassign bounty. That is my intention like, why don't user assign more bounty and wait till 4 week without reassign bounty.